# Access specific group by time intervals

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have been trying to make a query work for grouping time intervals in 15 min lots.

However, even based on posts here or elsewhere, my query still returns the data by individual minutes and not in 15 min intervals. I am using Access and wondering if that is a limitation on Access or am I just missing something obvious.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

```
SELECT DATEADD("n", DATEDIFF("n", 0, [Trade.Date] ) / 15 * 15, 0), [Trade.Value]
FROM Trade
```

Answer (score 0):

Grouping requires a `group by` clause.  For example:

```
SELECT  DATEADD("n", DATEDIFF("n", 0, [Trade.Date] ) / 15 * 15, 0)
,       avg([Trade.Value])
FROM    Trade
GROUP BY
        DATEADD("n", DATEDIFF("n", 0, [Trade.Date] ) / 15 * 15, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks Andomar. Apologies for the confusion. Yes, indeed I am missing the group by statement. My code above wanted to see if the SELECT portion of the query would result in 15-min time slots first (which it doesn't) prior to grouping the result using the GROUP BY part. So to be clear, I am wondering if this DATEADD("n", DATEDIFF("n", 0, [Trade.Date] ) / 15 * 15, 0) function is correctly returning me the desired results.

Comment: I should add that my query results, even with the GROUP BY statement, return a dataset that appears to have group them them by minute. Thanks!